# CSS: Select each last row in a group in a table?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a html `table`:

```
<table>
    <tr><th>row id</th><th>value</th></tr>
    <tr data-group-id="A" class="row A"><td>A1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr data-group-id="A" class="row A"><td>A2</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr data-group-id="B" class="row B"><td>B1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr data-group-id="B" class="row B"><td>B2</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr data-group-id="B" class="row B"><td>B3</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to select last rows of each group identified by `data-group-id` and `class`. So in the example above, `A2` and `B3` rows are what I want to select and add some styles on. I wonder if it is possible using pure CSS?

Comment: Nope, not with pure CSS. You'd have to use JavaScript. Pseudo-classes like :last-child select elements, not classes of elements.

Comment: A saner approach would be to separate the groups by putting them in <tbody>s.

Comment: @MrLister, agreed. But unfortunately the table is generated by a library that I can't modify.

Comment: If the groups are always 2 rows the best you can do is `nth-of-type(odd)` and the like.

Comment: @zer00ne@Michael_B  the number of rows within a group are undetermined, not fixed.

Comment: If the group IDs are known beforehand, you could use `:nth-last-child(1 of [data-group-id="A"]), :nth-last-child(1 of [data-group-id="B"])`. But I think no browser has implemented that yet.

Comment: Really confused.. aren't `tr.row.B td { CSS }` or `tr.row.A td { CSS }` enough? Is there some reason basic sectors don't work?

Comment: @Scott, he wants to select the last of each group.

Comment: @Oriol, no they are not known beforehand. The data is fetched from a service.

Comment: Then `tr.row.A:last-of-type td { CSS }` maybe.

Comment: @Scott `:last-of-type` means last-of-type, not last-of-class. B3 is the only last-of-type row.